# Equational theory of the orthocenter

Tags: lo.logic, mg.metric-geometry, model-theory, universal-algebra, triangles

*Previously [asked at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4306473/is-there-a-finite-basis-for-the-equational-theory-of-the-orthocenter):*

Briefly speaking, I'm looking for a description of the equational theory of the **orthocenter function**, $\mathsf{orth}$. By $\mathsf{orth}$ I mean the (partial) function sending a triple $(a,b,c)$ of noncollinear points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to the orthocenter of the resulting triangle.

Since the orthocenter function is partial - if $x,y,z$ are collinear then $\mathsf{orth}(x,y,z)$ doesn't exist - a bit of care is needed to make this precise. I'm not familiar with partial universal algebra, so I'll adopt the following brute-force fix: let $T$ be the deductive closure, in the sense of *standard* equational logic, of the set of all equations in $\mathsf{orth}$ which are true on a dense open set of inputs. Basically, this lets us ignore partiality issues. For example, the equation $$\mathsf{orth}(x,x,x)=\mathsf{orth}(x,x,x)$$ is bonkers for *any* input, but is a tautology in the sense of standard equational logic, so is in $T$.

There is a natural candidate for an equational axiomatization of $T$:

- The *symmetry equations* $$\mathsf{orth}(x,y,z)=\mathsf{orth}(y,z,x)\mbox{ and }\mathsf{orth}(x,y,z)=\mathsf{orth}(x,z,y),$$ and
- the *involutivity equation* $$\mathsf{orth}(x,y,\mathsf{orth}(x,y,z))=z.$$

> **Question**: Do these three equations in fact yield an axiomatization of $T$? If not, is $T$ finitely based at all? *(EDIT: I've gone ahead and [asked the finite basedness question separately](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426245/is-the-orthocenter-roughly-equationally-finitely-based).)*

(It may be helpful, towards a negative solution, to consider the analogues of $T$ corresponding to the two other known "involutive" triangle center functions, [$X(74)$ and $X(1138)$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407981/are-there-infinitely-many-generalized-triangle-vertices). Since each of these correspond to functions satisfying the above equations in the appropriate sense, an equation "true" about the orthocenter but "false" about $X(74)$ or $X(1138)$ would answer the question. However, I don't see such an equation.)

Comment: I don't know the answer to your specific question, but the universal algebra with partial opeations exists, see Palmgren & Vickers [Partial Horn logic and cartesian categories](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2006.10.001).

Comment: Doesn't, e.g., $X\left(74\right)$ provide a negative answer to the first half of your question?

Comment: Incidentally, the appropriate topic for this question might be closer to invariant theory than to logic, as you're looking for rational functions with a certain property.

Comment: @darijgrinberg "Doesn't, e.g., $X(74)$ provide a negative answer to the first half of your question?" I don't see how. Is there an equation which the orthocenter satisfies but $X(74)$ doesn't? (Two very different triangle centers may still be equationally indistiguishable.)

Comment: Well, your three equations hold both for the orthocenter and for $X\left(74\right)$, so they cannot axiomatize the orthocenter.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I think you're misunderstanding what "axiomatize the [theory of the] orthocenter" means in this context. While quite different geometrically, $X(74)$ and the orthocenter may still have the same equational theories.

Comment: For $X(74)$ to be a counterexample, what we'd need is an equation that $X(4)$ *does* satisfy but $X(74)$ *doesn't*. There might be one, but I don't immediately see it.

Comment: Ah, I misread "axiomatize the theory of the orthocenter" as "axiomatize the orthocenter".

Comment: @darijgrinberg FWIW my expectation in fact is that there is relatively little equational variation amongst the various natural triangle center functions.

Comment: I find it hard to imagine an equation that the orthocenter or $X\left(74\right)$ might satisfy that does not follow formally from your equations. Seeing that you cannot have two equal arguments, the set $\left\{A,B,C,H\right\}$ (where $H$ is the orthocenter of $ABC$) is closed under building orthocenters, and all of this is deducible from the axioms. So $H$ and $X\left(74\right)$ should yield the same theory. Modulo any nasty surprises that could appear on formalizing this handwaving, that is.

Comment: @darijgrinberg What about equations involving more than four points?

Comment: Ah, I forgot these exist too...

Comment: I think that $OA=OB$ iff there are $C,D,E$ with $O=orth(ABC)=orth(BCD)=orth(CDA)=orth(DAB)$, and if so you can probably build up enough basic geometry that the equations theory won’t be finitely axiomatizable.

Comment: @MattF. I don't see how that would lead to the *equational* theory being too complicated - it seems to me that any implementation of geometry along those lines would crucially relie on both an existential quantifier and a conditional, which aren't part of the equational theory.

Comment: Maybe you could work on the projective plane to make $\operatorname{orth}$ defined and continuous outside the diagonal.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$\newcommand{\o}[0]{\mathsf{orth}}$No, these equations do not yield the complete theory of the orthocenter.

The identity

$$\o(\o(t,u,v),\o(t,u,w),u) = \o(\o(t,u,v),\o(t,v,w),v)$$

holds for the orthocenter (X(4)) but not for [X(74)](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html) (the isogonal conjugate of the Euler infinity point), even though both satisfy involutory identities like

$$v=\o(t,u,\o(t,u,v))$$

I found the first identity and tested both using Mathematica, which can set up the functions quickly as follows:

```
avg[a_, b_, c_, u_, v_, w_] := (a u + b v + c w)/(a + b + c);    
bary[f_, u_, v_, w_] := avg[f[u,v,w], f[v,w,u], f[w,u,v], u, v, w];
cosA[u_, v_, w_] := (v-u).(w-u) / Sqrt[((v-u).(v-u)) ((w-u).(w-u))];
f[u_, v_, w_] := 1/((u-v).(u-w));
g[u_, v_, w_] := Sqrt[(v-w).(v-w)] / (cosA[u,v,w] - 2 cosA[v,w,u] cosA[w,u,v]);
center4[u_, v_, w_]  := bary[f, u, v, w];
center74[u_, v_, w_] := bary[g, u, v, w];
```

Then the following code tests the identity for the orthocenter algebraically, and for the X(74) center numerically:

```
Algebra = {t -> {tx, ty}, u -> {ux, uy}, v -> {vx, vy}, w -> {wx, wy}};
Example = {t -> {0, 1}, u -> {2, 4}, v -> {-3, 5}, w -> {-2, 1}};  
FourVariable[c_] := c[c[t,u,v], c[t,u,w], u] == c[c[t,u,v], c[t,v,w], v];
{FourVariable[center4] /. Algebra // Simplify, FourVariable[center74] /. Example}
```

and the tests return True and False respectively.

Comment: Neat! Of course, the finite base question is still open, but this is very good to know (and surprising to me, personally).

Comment: I've accepted this and asked the finite-basedness question separately.

Comment: MathJax note: unlike with plain TeX, you *must not* follow your `$\newcommand…$` with a blank line outside of the dollar sign, or else it will appear as a spurious blank line at the beginning of your post.  I have edited accordingly. \\ Also, there is no need to declare a command explicitly as having no arguments, like `\newcommand\o[0]{…}`; just `\newcommand\o{…}` will have the same effect.  But of course maybe you know this latter and prefer to do it anyway for consistency.

Comment: @LSpice, thanks for the edit and the explanations — I will use them.

Comment: [This question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/286813/17064) concerning the composition law on cubic surfaces is similar to this one for the orthocenter, and I too struggled in framing it correctly with how to deal with universal identities for a partially defined operation.

Comment: @MattF.: Unsurprisingly, your identity also fails for $X(1138)$, the third of the known triangle centers satisfying the "involutory identity". (This makes me wonder what counterpart identities hold for $X(74)$ and $X(1138)$.) I've added your result to my work-in-progress ["Treatise"](https://tricochet.com/math/pdfs/TTTTC.pdf) on those centers. Please contact me (see the email address in the note) if you would prefer to be identified by your full name. ... Cheers!