# Is the orthocenter "(roughly) equationally finitely-based"?

Tags: lo.logic, mg.metric-geometry, model-theory, universal-algebra, triangles

Let $T$ be the "almost everywhere" equational theory of the orthocenter function, "tweaked appropriately" to avoid partiality issues (see [this earlier question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425526/equational-theory-of-the-orthocenter) for details). Some examples of equations in $T$ are as follows:

- All trivial equations such as $\mathsf{orth}(x,x,x)=\mathsf{orth}(x,x,x)$ (while if interpreted naively this is bonkers for any input $x$, it winds up in $T$ due to the partiality-avoidance fix mentioned above).
- The symmetry equations $\mathsf{orth}(x,y,z)=\mathsf{orth}(x,z,y)=\mathsf{orth}(y,z,x)$.
- The involutivity equation $\mathsf{orth}(\mathsf{orth}(x,y,z),y,z)=x$. (Again, this is slightly bonkers, but the "almost everywhere" bit above + the partiality fix addresses this.)
- Additionally, at the above-linked question Matt F. discovered that the equation $$\mathsf{orth}(\mathsf{orth}(x,y,z),\mathsf{orth}(x,y,w),y) = \mathsf{orth}(\mathsf{orth}(x,y,z),\mathsf{orth}(x,z,w),z)$$ is in $T$, but is *not* in the analogous theory for [the triangle center $X(74)$](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/etc.html). Since the latter does include the above three equations, Matt's equation is not redundant.

While I remain interested in additional equational facts about $\mathsf{orth}$ (properly tweaked per the above), I'd now like to focus on the "coarse complexity" of the equational theory:

> Is $T$ finitely based?

That is, is $T$ the deductive closure, in the sense of equational logic, of some finite set of equations?

---

I would also be interested in any "natural" models of $T$ - with more than one element, of course. Because of the scare quotes in the definition of $T$, the orthocenter itself does not actually yield a genuine model of $T$, and at a glance I don't see a natural way to totalize it so that $T$ in fact holds in the resulting structure. In particular, note that shifting to the projective plane doesn't immediately fix everything: think about the involutivity equation above, and consider what happens as $C$ moves along the line $AB$.

*(Here is one model of $T$: the underlying set is $\{a,b,c,d\}$, and the function $\mathsf{orth}$ is defined by setting $\mathsf{orth}(x,x,x)=x$, $\mathsf{orth}(x,x,y)=y$ if $y\not=x$, and $\mathsf{orth}(x,y,z)$ = the unique element of $\{a,b,c,d\}\setminus\{x,y,z\}$ if $\vert x,y,z\vert=3$. But I'm not really sure that counts as natural. Certainly it has no geometric flavor, which is a shame.)*