# Is the equational theory of this "orthocentrish" algebra finitely based?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, universal-algebra

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the algebra (in the sense of universal algebra) whose underlying set is the four-element set $\{a,b,c,d\}$ and whose structure consists just of the ternary operation $F$ defined as follows:

- $F(x,x,x)=x$.
- If $x\not=y$ then $F(x,x,y)=F(x,y,x)=F(y,x,x)=y$.
- If $x,y,z$ are pairwise distinct, then $F(x,y,z)$ is the unique element of $\{a,b,c,d\}\setminus \{x,y,z\}$.

This $\mathcal{A}$ is a kind of "toy (and total) model" of the orthocenter, from an equational perspective. In [another question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426245/is-the-orthocenter-roughly-equationally-finitely-based) I asked whether the equational theory of the orthocenter (appropriately construed) is finitely axiomatizable; in retrospect that seems more difficult than I'd expected, so I'd like to look at this toy model first:

> Is the equational theory of $\mathcal{A}$ finitely based?

Comment: Is the equational theory finitely based for any function on a finite domain?

Comment: @MattF.: No. In 1954, Roger Lyndon produce a nonfinitely based finite algebra with a single operation.

Comment: @KeithKearnes, now I see a simple example at https://people.math.sc.edu/mcnulty/talks/mckenziefest.pdf: the equational theory of matrix multiplication is not finitely based for the domain with six $2\times2$ matrices consisting of the identity, the zero matrix, and the four matrices which are zero except for a $1$ in one cell.

Comment: @MattF., that semigroup is inherently non finitely based.  It begins to no finitely generated (or even locally finite) variety of semigroups which is finitely based by a famous result of Mark Sapir which made use of symbolic dynamics

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This algebra is finitely based.

In fact, if you choose any bijection from $\{a,b,c,d\}$ to $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$, then you can transport the operation $F(x,y,z)$ to $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$ it find that it is $x-y+z$. The resulting algebra $\langle \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2; x-y+z\rangle$ is the square of the algebra $\langle \mathbb Z_2; x-y+z\rangle$. Since an algebra and its square have the same equational theory, the question reduces to: Is $\langle \mathbb Z_2; x-y+z\rangle$ finitely based?

Roger Lyndon proved in 1951 that all $2$-element algebras are finitely based. In his paper, the algebra $\langle \mathbb Z_2; x-y+z\rangle$ is referred to as 'system $L_4$'. This is one of fifteen systems he deals with in Section I of his paper. Lyndon does not provide an equational basis for this algebra, but writes *``a complete set of axioms [for each of the systems in Section I] can be chosen by inspection from the various familiar sets of axioms for Boolean algebras and Boolean rings''*.

I claim that the following identities suffice:

- $F(x,x,y) = F(x,y,x) = F(y,x,x) = y$.
- $F(F(x_1,x_2,x_3),F(y_1,y_2,y_3),F(z_1,z_2,z_3))=F(F(x_1,y_1,z_1),F(x_2,y_2,z_2),F(x_3,y_3,z_3)).$

The reason these are enough is that $F(x,x,y)=F(y,x,x)=y$ (part of the first bullet point) states that $F$ is a Maltsev operation. The law from the second bullet point states that $F$ commutes with itself. H. P. Gumm showed that any Maltsev operation that commutes with itself on a set $A$ must be $x-y+z$ for some abelian group structure on $A$. Now the law $F(x,y,x) = y$ implies that $-y=y$ for this abelian group. Hence any model of the bulleted identities must be $\langle A; F(x,y,z)\rangle$ where $F(x,y,z) = x-y+z$ for some abelian group of exponent $2$ on $A$. Any two such things have the same equational theory.  In fact, if $\langle A; F(x,y,z)\rangle$ and $\langle B; F(x,y,z)\rangle$ are nontrivial and satisfy these identities, then each is embeddable in a power of the other. This is enough to prove that the set of bulleted identities axiomatizes an equationally complete theory, hence forms a basis of identities for any of its nontrivial models.

Comment: The basis can be simplified to $F(x,y,x)=y$ and $F(x,y,z)=F(F(x,y,w),z,w)$. By setting $w=x$, this implies $F(x,y,z)=F(y,z,x)$, thus also $F(x,x,y)=F(y,x,x)=y$, and then by setting $w=y$, it implies $F(x,y,z)=F(x,z,y)$, thus $F$ is fully symmetric. Then it is easy to see that if you fix an arbitrary element $0$ and define $x+y=F(x,y,0)$, then $+$ forms an abelian group of exponent $2$, and $F(x,y,z)=x+y+z$. Abelian groups of exponent $2$ axiomatize the equational theory of $\langle\{0,1\},+\rangle$.